# Can the iOS 7 Simulator work with Xcode 4.6.3?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode4.6

Tried copying over the iOS 7.0 Simulator to the Xcode 4.6.3 bundle in the correct location.  It does show up in the Device List, and the simulator starts, but then pinwheels.

I had to hard stop the simulator and Xcode.  I'm mainly just curious, but wanted to know if this should work or can work.

Comment: ios7 is under NDA, you should post in Apple Developer Forum

Comment: Speaking about iOS7 is not under NDA - where is the harm in this question?

Comment: You have to start the IOS 7 Simulator using XCODE 5.  XCode 4 can not start the ios 7 Siumulator. See step 5 below. Also see step 3.5 which is new.  Nothing like a -1 for no reason.

Comment: The big thing is "Why?". Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Read the book waiting for godot and then you will know why the last comment just does not matter.

Comment: 12k views and one up vote.....     :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how to run the IOS 7.0 Simulator under the Xcode 4.6.3 version.

0) Make a backup point for the Mac

1) Download and install the Xcode 5 Beta X

2) Make sure that the IOS 7 simulator is working for Xcode 5 with IOS 7 Simulator

3) Stop all simulators and Xcodes

3.5) Make duplicate of the current Xcode 4 and do 4) to the duplicate app bundle

4) Copy

/Applications/Xcode5-DP3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/

to

/Applications/Xcode copy.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/

5) Start the proper simulator in 7.0 mode using Xcode 5 and a sample app, etc.

6) Stop Xcode 5

7) Start Xcode 4 *COPY* and choose the same 7.0 simulator and run your app (Xcode 4 is not "smart" enough to start the 7.0 simulator).

8) Should show up in the 7.0 simulator

Comment: it worked BUT Xcode4 does not fully support Simulator iOS7. In my project I can see lots of bugs on iOS7 Simulator but not on iOS device...

Comment: What I have found is that for some reason the build under the XCODE 4.6.3 sometimes "goes strange" after running the IOS7 simulator.  This does not happen all of the time.  Something to do with NIB / XIB reading.  I delete the Xcode 4.6.3 copy, copy from the main install, move the simulator and start use again and all is fine.  I have not traced down why this is happening only sometimes.  I don't see this as a super solution, but for some testing without hardware this will fit some bills.

Comment: yep, that is exactly what I experienced

Comment: Please see the below solution that did not used to work but does now.  A little bit simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Simple!

Open the iOS7 simulator from the XCode 5 Pacakage folder

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications

Keep the iOS7 Simulator open. Now Open your XCode 4.6 build your project with Simulator selected. The app will be now opened in the iOS7 Simulator.

If the app quits or not running, Try Reseting the Simulator contents or Clean the project and keep trying. It works for me.

Comment: At the time of the posting, this did not work, but now it does with the later versions of XCode 5 / simulator.  It used to restart the simulator in the version selected in XCode 4.  So this now works.

Comment: If this is working then copying simulator to Xcode 4 folder and running it from there should work too.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. iOS7 only works with Xcode 5 DP.

Comment: You mean the simulator?  4.6.3 apps work / run fine from the app store on the hardware with IOS 7 Beta.  Just want to test our current 4.6.3 builds on an IOS 7.0 simulator instead of hardware.....

Comment: Ya doing the same thing myself. Unfortunately seems like you need to run the project from within DP5. Shouldn't be a big problem. Am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Nope, because even if I set the BASE SDK to 6.1 and run in Xcode 5, get different results than if running Xcode 4 app in IOS 7

Comment: Looking through your conversation I would consider what you're trying to accomplish as a creative idea but a bad one. Using the simulator to 
"ignore" what happens on physical hardware isn't good practice because that's what you're doing when you want to "test builds on a simulator instead of hardware".

Comment: Turns out that out of the box this can't be done, but check the other answer and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to run the IOS 7.0 Simulator under the Xcode 4.6.3 version, after copyint it to the right location described above:

- Start XCode 5 running a sample app within the iOS simulator
- Change settings of the simulator to keep it in dock
- Quit XCode 5
- Change requested hardware in iOS simulator which is still running
- Start XCode 4.6.3 running your app within the iOS simulator after selecting the hardware set within the simulator -  they must be equal.

That´s it !

Furtheron you only need to start the simulator first, set the requested hardware, start XCode 4.6.3 with equal hardware set in the simulator and RUN.

Answer (score -1):

Simpler answer to run a Xcode 4 project on iOS7:

1. Backup your 4.6 project. (either physical backup or commit to github or svn)
2. Open your project in Xcode 5 DP
3. Xcode 5 will make changes to the files, but that's OK because you made a backup
4. Run the app with Xcode5 and iOS7
5. When you are done, restore your project with the backup you made earlier
6. ???
7. Profit

Comment: Unfortunately Xcode 5 (and iOS 7 SDK) is a lot different, so the chances are high, that your app will fall apart when you build with it.